# vba excel conditional formatting on listObject

Tags: excel, vba

I need to strikeout a row cells depending of a relative column value in a listobject.
How i can add a conditional formatting on all row cells based on relative column value in vba?
Ex: If the cell value = 1, then the entire row need to be strikeout

I tried this:

```
Dim qt As ListObject
qt = Sheets.ListObjects(1)
With qt.DataBodyRange
.FormatConditions.Delete
.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=[MyColumn]=0"
.FormatConditions(0).Font.StrikeOut = True
End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following uses the [.DataBodyRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.listobject.databodyrange.aspx) to retrieve the address in the top-left corner to be used in a formuLa.

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With .ListObjects("Table1")
        With .DataBodyRange
            .FormatConditions.Delete
            .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, _
                Formula1:="=" & .Cells(1, 1).Address(0, 1) & "=1"
            .FormatConditions(1).Font.Strikethrough = True
        End With
    End With
End With
```

Note that the [FormatConditions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195304.aspx) object has a 1-based ineex and the use of [Font.Strikethrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841197.aspx) property, not Font.StrikeOut.

Comment: Just perfect!
My bad i confused strikeout with Strikethrough!